# Exploring a maze (using python 2.7)

Tags: python

I have done everything on my homework except a one step.

I did it in a different way, but it gave kind of right answer somehow.
Anyway, I have to explore a maz, so I went all the way through and got everything completely right, except part (Q COMMAND) of this task.

I need to use string method `.upper()`

2.2.6 The Top-Level Interface
`interact()` is the top-level function that denes the text-base user interface
as described in the introduction. 
Note that when either the user quits or
when the finish square is found, the interact function should exit.

```
def interact():
    mazefile = raw_input('Maze File: ')
    maze = load_maze(mazefile)
    position = (1, 1)
    poshis = [position]

    while True:
        #print poshis, len(poshis)
        print 'You are at position', position
        command = raw_input('Command: ')
        #print command

        if command == '?':
            print HELP
        elif command == 'N' or command == 'E' or command == 'S'or command == 'W':
            mov = move(maze, position, command)
            if mov[0] == False: #invalid direction
                print "You can't go in that direction" 
            elif mov[1] == True:#finished
                print 'Congratulations - you made it!'
                break
            else: #can move, but not finished
                position = mov[2]
                poshis.append(position) 

        elif command == 'R': # reseting the maze to the first pos
            position = (1, 1)
            poshis = [position]
        elif command == 'B': # back one move
            if len(poshis) > 1:
                poshis.pop()
                position = poshis[-1]

        elif command == 'L': # listing all possible leg dir
            toggle = 0
            result = ''
            leg_list = get_legal_directions(maze, poshis[-1])
            for Legal in leg_list:
                if toggle:
                    result += ', '
                    result += Legal
                else:
                    result += Legal
                if not toggle:
                    toggle = 1
            print result

        elif command == 'Q': #quiting 
            m = raw_input('Are you sure you want to quit? [y] or n: ')
            if m == 'y':
                break

            #print 'Are you sure you want to quit? [y] or n: '
            #if raw_input == 'y':
              #  break

        else: #invalid input
            print 'Invalid Command:', command
```

Comment: Is the question "Why doesn't it exit?"? What do you expect to happen? Why is Python 2.7 important? Could you post some details on the way you did not choose to solve the last part? Could you post two or three lines of the maze file?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't particularly clear, but I'm guessing that the 'problem' is that if a user were to answer "Y" instead of "y" when asked if they are sure they want to quit, then the loop will continue.

If that is the problem, you should merely replace the line:

```
if m == 'y':
    break
```

with:

```
if m.upper() == 'Y':
    break
```

Because regardless of whether the user types "y" or "Y", the loop will still be broken out of.

Comment: but i have to use this as my teacher said:                         
the user input in interact function should be converted to uppercase when asking for user commands.have alook at string method.upper() 
eg.'asdf'.upper() ->'ASDF'
also when quitting in interact,[y] means that quitting is the default option,so basicly if user types in 'N' they shouldn't quit, any other input should quit.
eg.
'Are you sure you want to quit? [y] or n: ''N' -> don't quit
'Are you sure you want to quit? [y] or n: ''Y' -> quit
'Are you sure you want to quit? [y] or n: ''asdf' -> quit